# 2 USB Sound Cards in Raspberry Pi

Tags: bluetooth, usb-audio

I have a pair of Alesis Active Monitors which have a USB input and it's a pain connecting devices to it so I felt using a Rasberry Pi with bluetooth and audio ins to allow for multiple connections maybe a way around it.

My plan would be to have a Raspberry Pi Zero W or something in future but i'm just testing with a Raspberry Pi B+ which was laying around. I want to plug the speakers into it via USB and use as the only audio out however then have a bluetooth in mode and analog audio in so may need a second USB sound card with inputs and was wondering if this would work and how I could switch the inputs (e.g. use some kind of switch on GPIO or something that will run a script to change the inputs)

Before I buy some of these bits can anyone tell me if this will work?

Comment: The Pi does not have audio (or any analog) in, so you will need a sound card for that. There are many options. It sounds like you want to have it in a self-contained box, and then you need to handle the power and shutdown, ie it is not good to just turn off the power without doing a OS shutdown first, which then needs to be triggered in advance. Also, have you checked that the speakers work with the Pi at all? A button on GPIO is simple (I hear).

Comment: Not yet tested the speakers no, but yeah it registers in windows as another USB audio device that's why i'm wondering if ill have trouble with the second soundcard for analog inputs. Ill work out the shutdown thing after but really i'm not planning on having it ever turn off.

Comment: 2nd sound card should not be a problem. The question is if the speaker drivers are available for ARM, or if there are other drivers that work with those speakers. You can find that out first without buying anything.

Comment: Yeah kool thats good. Ill test the speakers tomorrow and see how it goes hopefully the speakers are fine but guess that will be a headache for tomorrow.